# Regex to allow sub domains

Tags: javascript, regex

Following regex working fine cases where domain is root domain, but this regex not recognizing sub domains as valid domains:

For example: `abc.com` is being recognized as valid domain, but if I use `ab.bc.com` then regex says string is not valid, how can I improve this to supprt `ab.bc.com` too?

```
  var reg = /^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/;
    if ( !reg.test(the_domain)) 
    {
       alert('has special characters');
    } 
    else 
     {
       alert('no special characters');
     }
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lzufkrw4/1/)

Comment: You can use: `/^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/`

Comment: For completeness sake: top level domain names don't always follow the pattern `\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}`. In particular, [internationalized domain names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name) such as `.рф` don't match because they use non-latin characters, and even in their ASCII ([punycode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode)) form (`.xn--p1ai`), they don't match because they contain dashes and digits.

Comment: @Frxstrem: agree, but for now domain names with internationalization is not a priority. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a quantifier for the *xx.* pattern, and make it as `/^([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/`

```js
var reg = /^([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/;
//                                   ^                  ^   changes made
console.log(reg.test("abc.com"));
console.log(reg.test("ab.bc.com"));
console.log(reg.test("a-b.bc.com"));
console.log(reg.test("ab-.bc.com"));
```

Comment: This seems working, will test little bit more. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`/^(\S+\.\S+)$/`

This makes sure it has at least a word with a period and another word, if it repeats then its fine.

https://jsfiddle.net/3yb1v222/

or to be more restrictive on characters you can just do:

`/^[A-Za-z0-9-_&\?]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9-_&\?]+){1,2}/`

you can remove the additional special characters if you are excluding the path on any given url, but either way... its the same concept.

https://jsfiddle.net/u7hgabec/

Comment: Nice. Thank you!